# How to add an action to copy data from one table_column to another table_column in rails_admin?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, custom-action, rails-admin

I am using rails_admin 0.0.5 and want to add a functionality (if not exist).

I want to copy data from one table to another. I have two database tables, both accessible from rails_admin. How to copy one attribute from one table to another.

eg. 
requests_table => emails|request_approve

approval_table => emails|sent_confirmation

and I want to copy emails from approval_table to emails in approval_table.

I didn't understand this, so please do not refer. https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Custom-action

Comment: This is a large question. I would advise breaking the question down into smaller chunks. For example, you can start with how do I copy data from one table to another. And further move on to how do I restrict access on certain attributes of a model etc..

Comment: Hi, I edited the question. I think it is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

This method will copy all the requests and save them in approval table.
I would add another attribute called, `copied` to request table. This would indicate those requests that's been copied already and avoid duplicates in approval table.

```
def copy_table
  @requests = Request.find_all_by_copied(false)
  @requests.each do |r|
    @approval = Approval.new
    @approval.email = r.email
    @approval.sent_confirmation = r.request_approve
    @approval.save
    @requests.update_attributes(:copied => false)
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi, I am looking for this in rails_admin. Not directly... I want to append this in rails_admin only.

Comment: rails_admin probably doesn't have a method that specifically copies table to table that's catered to your need. Include this method maybe in admin model and you can use it within Rails.